# About LAMBDA editor

Tags: math-software

I'm a graduate student and I've working about a year ago with blind students. I teach basic math to them (euclidean geometry, calculus, algebra, etc...) and recently I've heard about LAMBDA project (Linear Access to Mathematic for Braille Device and Audio-synthesis). This is a program that allows to work with JAWS (a screen reader software), and it seems very useful to the purpose of introduce this students to college maths.

The question is, if someone knows a tutorial about LAMBDA and how to use it.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Some links: [lambda home page](http://www.lambdaproject.org/), [publication](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11788713_176)